# Unable to invoke web-request for script called in scheduled task for service account

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

We have a Powershell script which downloads some zip files from a website and we have called the script in a scheduled task.

The problem is we are not getting the zip files even after the scheduled task is finished successfully. We are using a service account for that. Running the script manually downloads the zip file without any issues. Also, for another user which we use to login into the server, the task is working fine.

The issue started after our service account got locked out because of too many failed attempts in some other system.

I have tried bypassing the execution policy but no luck.
I have tried creating a similar new task but no luck.
I tried `Start-in` option to provide the task the location of the script but no luck.

After too much troubleshooting, I found the error in the Powershell logs in Event Viewer. Please find the error below:

```
Error Message = Unable to connect to the remote server
Fully Qualified Error ID = WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

This shows that the task is unable to invoke the web request. Can this be a permission issue? If yes, then how can I provide the required access?

I troubleshooted a bit more and found that the issue is with the proxy. Can somebody tell me how can I resolve this issue? For the local user it is working fine. Even I am able to access the webpage manually through IE. Shall I import proxy settings from IE? If yes then how to do that?

Comment: "Unable to connect to the remote server" usually means failure to establish the http connections - could it be that the remote website from where you download the zip files recently updated their SSL/TLS certificate or configuration? Also, please post the full `Invoke-WebRequest` command being run

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : Hi Mathias. Thanks for your reply. Will be able to post the ful request tomorrow as I don't have it now. Also, if the SSL/TLS certificate has been updated, then even running the script manually shouldn't give any zip files downloaded. Correct me if I am wrong. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: I troubleshooted a bit more and found that the issue is with the proxy. Can somebody tell me how can I resolve this issue? For the local user it is working fine. Even I am able to access the webpage manually through IE. Shall I import proxy settings from IE? If yes then how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution for this. I added proxy details in the script which will force the Invoke web request command to send the request to that proxy server. This  thing has resolved my issue.

Regards,
Mitesh Agrawal